# Magento admin url does not load

Tags: admin

when Iam trying to access Magento admin page, the page does not loaded instead XAMPP home page has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you write localhost or ip , the default index page is running and you will land at xampp dashboard:
http://localhost/dashboard/

You can try with this like http://localhost/YourMangentoFolderName/admin or any custom name you set instead of "**admin**" to access your store admin.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem in windows I have edited two files.

> /Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

Add a line at the bottom like:

```
localhost sitename.local
```

> /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Add at the bottom:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/apps/magento/htdocs"
       ServerName sitename.local
</VirtualHost>
```

You may need to change the above to use your correct IP address (localhost), port number, and document root path. Then you will access the site in your browser by typing in sitename.local or whatever you changed it to.